# Jquery Mobile, override back button (browser or phone)

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my Jquery Mobile app, I would to override the browser or phone back button (that is available on Android devices).
On the page #welcome-page only, and only if the previous-page id is #signin-page, I would like the back button to skip the #signin-page (not even callthe associated js) and go to #explanation-page.

Can you help me achieve this ?

For now I did the following but it messes everything up, because it seems to load #signin-page.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#welcome-page', function(event, docdata){  //jqm 1.4
console.log('previous page was ' +docdata.prevPage.attr('id'));
    if ( docdata.prevPage.attr('id') == 'signin-page') {
        $(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
            var direction = data.state.direction;
            if (direction == 'back') {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('back button pressed');
                //$( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#explanation-short", { transition: "fade" });
            }
            $(window).off("navigate");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: previous page in DOM or in history?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5Vg7T/

Comment: Hi @Omar, the app is a "single page app" so I guess it's previous in DOM. Thanks for the code, I just tested it in my app, and it seems that pagecontainerbeforechange is not fired...(I am using JQM 1.4.2), any idea why ?

Comment: ok I am seeing your blog post here :http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/pagecontainerbeforechange/ pagecontainerbeforechange is only working from jQM 1.4.3. Ok so I've updated my version of JQM to 1.4.3 (any major change I should be aware of by the way ??), and now it almost works...but it fires even if the user goes from `welcome-page` to `signin-page` without pressing the back button (there's a place in the app where this happens...)

Comment: I also get a very weird behavior: the first time from signin-page to welcome-page, and press back, goes to explanation-short,which is fine. But the second time I go to signin-page and then to welcome-page, if I press back, it goes to explanation-short and comes back immediately to welcome-page...Could it be because pagecontainerbeforechange is fired twice ? Isn't there an event that is only fired once ?

Comment: It seems that the whole things fires event when the back button is not pressed...are your sure `$(window).on("navigate"` is fired before `$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange"` ?

Comment: I think I found a first problem : I use several `select` with `data-native-menu="false"` on the welcome-page and when JQM gets out of the dialogs it sets data.state.direction to "back", so at the next `pagecontainerbeforechange` data.state.direction is unfortunately set to "back" and your code fires. Is there a way to counteract this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57813/discussion-between-omar-and-louis).

Comment: have you managed to get this solved?